# how to access to reactjs in local network

Tags: reactjs, linux, networking, local-network

I'm running a reactjs in linux and I'm trying to access it from another device in the same network ,I saw these questions [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586592/why-cant-i-access-my-react-app-from-another-device),[q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657023/cant-access-create-app-react-app-via-local-network),[q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64946160/how-can-i-open-react-app-on-local-network) but didn't help , I turned off firewall , I run "npm start --host 0.0.0.0" didn't work either,I try it from my phone, it always ends by "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT",
I created app by create-app-react and I run it by npm start.

Comment: Do you try to access correct IP?

Comment: @Konrad yes , I try to ping on the ip address it worked and in the same machine I build a drf api which I was able to access it from another device and with the same ip .

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to run :

> sudo ufw allow 3000

(change 3000 by your port )